# How and where to inflate a button in a custom view

Tags: android, android-layout

My current usecase is to inflate 3+ buttons in a custom view. I want to build a custom view that takes the width and deciphers how to show the 3+ buttons. If the buttons dont fit with the text on it in one single horizontal arrangement, the buttons are placed vertically one after the other. So to work on that I know that I need to run through the onMeasure pass. Should I inflate each buttons over here in onMeasure or should I inflate it after the constructor CustomButtonBarView?

So the architecture I want to follow is kind of like

```
public CustomButtonBarView extends ViewGroup
{
   public CustomButtonBarView( Context context )
   {
       //initialize variables
   } 

   public void onMeasure()
   {
         // inflate all the buttons more than 3 
         // measure each button width, then see if it can be fitted in one
         // line and then move forward
   }
}
```

So my question is where should I inflate those 3+ buttons? I cannot put them in the XML as the exact number is different

```
<CustomButtonBarView>
  <Button/>
  <Button/> <!-- NO idea how many -->
</CustomButtonBarView>
```

Thanks, any help or direction or even if you feel my direction is incorrect feel free to let me know. I am open to changes.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the buttons in a grid view might help. There you can force the buttons to follow a grid. The OS will handle the width of the button so you might need to measure them.